# Munin access to MySQL

Tags: mysql, centos5, munin

According to several tutorials, the following should work:

Create a new user in MySQL.

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
> CREATE USER 'munin'@'localhost';
> exit;
```

Use that user in munin to access the database:
edit `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node`. At [mysql*] set the following:

```
[mysql*]
env.mysqlopts -u munin
```

Strange thing, is that running

```
 /usr/sbin/munin-node-configure --suggest | grep mysql
```

Which tells me that MySQL cannot access the database and that it tries to access the database using user **root**:

```
[DBI connect('mysql;mysql_connect_timeout=5','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is a CentOS 5.5 machine.

Why should munin-node-configure ignore the setting in /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node? Should I set this elsewhere? Reloading or restarting the munin-node deamon changes nothing either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me wildcards didnt seem to work either but the following did work

```
[mysql_queries]  
env.mysqlopts -u dev1
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, but it did not solve anything. to me, it looks like the configuration file is not loaded at all.

Comment: This answer brought me on track. It turns out that munin-node-configure somehow ignores the settings in [mysql_queries], but once enabled and restarted the sensor /does/ turn up data.

Answer (score 2):

For Munin 1.4.7 there is error in documentation: mysql plugin looks for environment variables using another name.

You can check /usr/share/munin/plugins/mysql_

```
my %config = (
    'dsn'        => $ENV{'mysqlconnection'} || 'DBI:mysql:mysql',
    'user'       => $ENV{'mysqluser'}       || 'root',
    'password'   => $ENV{'mysqlpassword'}   || '',
);
```

So because the script doesn't check 'mysqlopts' I had to set up

```
[mysql*]
env.mysqluser username
env.mysqlpassword pass
```

then restart munin-node (just to be on the safe side).